# Spring Hibernate Connection from database not released

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate

I am getting the following error below

```
Unexpected error 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:

**CannotCreateTransactionException:** Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBC
    Exception: Could not open connection
```

Here is the scenario in which it occurs :

I have recently moved some table from mysql to mongo. The code is written in such a way that either data would be taken from mongo/mysql.

The code is written in a method block which is annotated with @**Transactional** provided by spring framework.

There is hibernate layer which is using transaction provided by spring. c3p0 is the connection pool.

The parameter of connection pool is

```
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5    
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1200   
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=35      
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
```

The problem comes when we try to pull the data from mongo.Looks like the transaction is not getting closed because of mongo operation.The database connection is not getting released .It reaches the max size defined in the pool.

Tried the query in DB to find out the connection

```
show status like '%onn%';
```

Any suggestion to resolve this would really help.

Thanks

Comment: Not a fan of the "hibernate to MongoDB" effort here as it is far to focused on standard relational concepts that do not fit a NoSQL ( and non-relational ) engine. MongoDB has no concept of transactions and/or "rollback". The general premise is that when using the engine you need to write your own handling for such situations where an error in multiple updates occurs. You can kind of do this "Java Side" but it takes some work. I strongly doubt the hibernate connection adapter does any of this. Do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way To escape from a transaction in certaincases .